# vw fox unlocking door by key opens window

Tags: vw, locks, central-locking, fox

I have recently bought 2005 vw fox 1.4l.

I got a problem with central locking and door lock. The key fob started to fail and after few days it was not working anymore (Batteries were good and key light was working), I could not lock the car so I tried to do the thing with the key and door lock. However when I tried to lock the car with key - it didn't work. Then I locked the car via buttons on inside door panel and when I tried to unlock the door, instead of unlocking, both windows (driver and passenger side) opened.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? The thing that I can not lock/unlock the car with key and remotely is really frustrating. Also do you have any idea why windows open when I try to unlock the door via key?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the VW Fox because I'm an American, but it sounds like the central locking controller could be at fault or a fuse for the locking mechanisms is blown.  On the VW's that I have had, the key was mechanically connected to the lock mechanism, but from what I can tell, the platform your car is on has purely electric locks.  So if you have a dead battery, or the locking controller messes up, you may not be able to unlock your doors.

Another feature that has been around for some time on VW is if you insert your key and hold it locked, the windows roll up.  Hold it unlocked and the windows roll down.  If you're holding your key in position, that would account for the windows.

Check for blown fuses, and if everything looks good, the locking controller could be at fault.

Comment: Great point about the auto roll down when key is all the way over. Was thinking the same thing myself, but seeing as how I've ever only owned one VW, hardly makes me an expert.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've had enough VWs that I even have the official [VW T-Shirt](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61k8CLkPASL._UX385_.jpg)...